Reducing the disk space of an Oracle virtual machine
I have allocated too much memory on my virtual machine and there is not much left on my host one. I want to reduce my memory on my virtual machine and my host one to take it. My host machine is Windows and my virtual machine guest OS is Ubuntu.
I tried:
On my virtual machine I used GParted to make a new partition with the memory I want to free and allocate by my host one:
How I have allocated my partitions:

I did this in order to zero out my new partition and use Oracle's modifymedium --compact command to free this memory, but this didn't work.
This is the command I used to zero out the space:
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of="New Partition #1" bs=1M

Somewhere I read that I need a specific path of this partition in order to be sure that the command would work, but it seemed like something happened after that command and I didn't provide a path since it looks like it isn't assigned any. After lsblk I get:
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2846
loop1                       7:1    0  63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1828
loop2                       7:2    0  91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
loop3                       7:3    0   132M  1 loop /snap/docker/2932
loop4                       7:4    0  63.7M  1 loop /snap/core20/2434
loop5                       7:5    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/1663
loop6                       7:6    0 139.6M  1 loop /snap/docker/2963
loop7                       7:7    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/1722
loop8                       7:8    0  91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/29619
loop9                       7:9    0   1.1M  1 loop /snap/mosquitto/904
loop10                      7:10   0  44.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/23258
loop11                      7:11   0  38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
loop12                      7:12   0  11.1M  1 loop /snap/ngrok/226
sda                         8:0    0 976.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   1.1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 488.3G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  

and /dev/sda3 is my main partition that I do not want to modify and want to keep as it is in my virtual machine.
This ia the output of modifymedium --compact :
./VBoxManage modifymedium --compact "..notImportantPathToShow\workspace1.vdi"
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%

however after all this nothing changes in my virtual machine.
